# (Unity) Is there a way to get notified when referenced object instance gets deleted/missed? [With build support]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So let's say we have MonoBehaviour class with a Transform property:

```
public class Class : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target; //An object is already referenced here.
}
```

Question is simple: is there a way to get an event or some sort of callback in case this object gets deleted (externally)?
*Unity will show this as "Missing":*

[image]

Since it is just a transform, you cannot really use `OnDestroy()` here, and even if you could this is not a good option because of how many transform instances there are.

**It should be noted that I need this to work at build, so in-editor only options are unfortunately not solving my problem.**

Comment: I don't think Unity can support this exact feature, but there could be a helpful answer to the underlying use case if that use case were described. See [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: A good place to start: it would help to explain why `Transform` was used as the type here - was `Transform` chosen arbitrarily or is there a notion that only `Transform` is an appropriate type here?

Comment: To describe my partial case - Target is used by the NPC's AI as object to "take into account": target to look at or object to pick up. It is possible for this target to be destroyed (by being picked up, or deleted if it is destructible - anything that makes this object to vanish via `Destroy(gameObject)` method) yet I can't check if this object is referenced before deletion since `Transform` is only thing targets they share in common, and creating script for every possible target object seems too patchy. Creating a delegate when Target is deleted could work, but I don't know when to Invoke it.

Comment: So, I think there might be a solution that might meet your expectations [if you are using DOTS](https://www.effectiveunity.com/ecs/06-how-to-build-reactive-systems-with-unity-ecs-part-1/) but my DOTS experience is too limited to say. Without using DOTS, best solutions I can think of are adding a monobehavior with an event to the transform's gameobject when it is selected as target if that g.o. doesn't already have it, and have an OnDestroy that fires the event, and have the npc sub/unsub to it as target is added/removed, or just checking every frame for `target==null.`

Comment: You speak about runtime or in the editor itself?

Comment: @derHugo runtime, that's what they mean by "at build"

Comment: @Ruzihm ah I see .. even though it's bold I somehow overread that last part of that sentence ^^ Though by `at` build I somehow thought they refer to actually the moment of the building (multi-scenes get unloaded etc)

Comment: Yeah I definitely understand the confusion - if I hadn't seen the previous edit of their previous question I don't think I would have recognized that was the meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I'd consider this a partial solution since there are some ways it's currently not ideal including not being able to edit prefabs while in play mode, leaving notify monobehaviours behind if AIs are destroyed, not respecting undo in the editor, and likely others. Still, this is probably worth sharing in its current state anyway.

Make a MonoBehaviour that will manage actions to call in the event the owning object is deleted. We're interested in making this work in the editor and at runtime, so I used the `UnityEvent` api for this.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.Events;


[System.Serializable]
public class DestroyEvent : UnityEvent { };

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DestructionNotifier : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DestroyEvent OnDestroyed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (OnDestroyed == null)
        {
            OnDestroyed = new DestroyEvent();
        }
    }

    public void Register(UnityAction act)
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if (EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode)
        {
            // add non-persistent listener if in play mode
            OnDestroyed.AddListener(act);
        }
        else
        {
            // add persistent listener if in edit mode
            UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.AddPersistentListener(
                    OnDestroyed, act);
            OnDestroyed.SetPersistentListenerState(
                    OnDestroyed.GetPersistentEventCount() - 1, 
                    UnityEventCallState.EditorAndRuntime);
        }
#else
        // add non-persistent listener
        OnDestroyed.AddListener(act);
#endif
    }

    public void Deregister(UnityAction call)
    {
        // remove or disable matching persistent actions
        for (int i = 0; i < OnDestroyed.GetPersistentEventCount(); i++)
        {
            if ((Object)call.Target == OnDestroyed.GetPersistentTarget(i))
            {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
                if (EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode)
                {
                    OnDestroyed.SetPersistentListenerState(i,
                            UnityEventCallState.Off);
                }
                else
                {
                    UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools
                            .RemovePersistentListener(OnDestroyed, i);
                }
#else
                OnDestroyed.SetPersistentListenerState(i, 
                        UnityEventCallState.Off);
#endif
            }
        }

        // remove matching non-persistent actions
        OnDestroyed.RemoveListener(call);

        // if in edit mode, remove self if no actions
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        RemoveEmptyEvents(); 
        if (!EditorApplication.isPlayingOrWillChangePlaymode
            && OnDestroyed.GetPersistentEventCount() == 0)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(this);
        }
#endif
}

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        RemoveEmptyEvents();
    }

    void RemoveEmptyEvents()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        for (int i = OnDestroyed.GetPersistentEventCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (OnDestroyed.GetPersistentTarget(i) == null)
            {
                UnityEditor.Events.UnityEventTools.RemovePersistentListener(
                        OnDestroyed, i);
            }
        }
#endif
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (OnDestroyed != null)
        {
            OnDestroyed.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your AI script, turn your transform into a property that uses a `DestructionNotifier` field to sub/unsub to the event as the target is changed. Use a custom inspector to allow the property to be edited in the inspector:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class Class : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTargetDestroyed()
    {
        // Stuff to do when target is destroyed
        Debug.Log($"{gameObject.name}: target destroyed.");
    }

    [SerializeField, HideInInspector] DestructionNotifier targetNotifier;

    public Transform Target {
        get { return targetNotifier == null ? null : targetNotifier.transform; }
        set {
            if (targetNotifier != null)
            {
                targetNotifier.Deregister(OnTargetDestroyed);
            }

            if (value == null)
            {
                targetNotifier = null;
                return;
            }

            targetNotifier = value.GetComponent<DestructionNotifier>();

            if (targetNotifier == null)
            {
                targetNotifier = value.gameObject
                        .AddComponent<DestructionNotifier>();
            }
            targetNotifier.Register(OnTargetDestroyed);
        }
    }
}

#if UNITY_EDITOR
[CustomEditor(typeof(Class)), CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class AIInspector : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Class targetAI = (Class)target;
        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        Transform newTarget = EditorGUILayout.ObjectField("Target", 
                targetAI.Target, typeof(Transform), true) as Transform;

        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            foreach (Class curTarget in targets)
            {
                curTarget.Target = newTarget;
            }
        }
        DrawDefaultInspector();
    }
}
#endif
```